# Cannot ping VPN server by tun address when connected

Tags: networking, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server set up in a datacenter running Debian. I am using a TUN interface to connect to it, and my Windows PC gets a `10.8.0.x` address, as expected. When I run `ip addr` on my server, I see its IP address on the tun adapter is `10.8.0.1`.

I cannot ping that address from Windows. I cannot ping Windows from the server when connected. My regular LAN IP range is `192.168.0.0/24`, so I know it's not a conflict there.

**What can I do to make something as simple as `ping` work?** `iptables -L` lists everything as ALLOW.

Below is my client config (sans keys):

```
client
dev tap
dev-node "Ethernet 3"
proto udp
remote 123.456.789.5 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
;remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

And the server config:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/crl.pem
```

On the server:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 04:01:83:ba:75:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 123.456.789.5/20 brd 123.456.789.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.20.0.5/16 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.0.1/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chosen different virtual devices on the client and on the server:

```
dev tap
dev tun
```

You should modify the one on the client to match that on the server. I do not know whether this is the **only** error in the configuration, but this is surely important enough to prevent a proper connection.

Comment: That was it... -.-